# Titlepage custom footnote - remove indentation locally (memoir class)

Tags: footnotes, memoir, titles

I am working on a template for a title page and I still cannot manage to adjust the indentation of my custom footnote using memoir class.

**Edit:**

I want to create copy the macro of `\thanks{}` that does not have any footnote mark and is also not indented. The normal `\thanks` command shall not be affected.

I tried to imitate the `\thanks` command but the results aren't good:

```
\newcommand\authordetail[1]{
  \setlength{\footparindent}{0em}        
  \protect\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{#1}}%
}
```

I don't want any indentation and just have the footnote start flushleft. However, this should only apply locally to the titlepage and using this command. All other footnotes should behave according to the default setting.

Adding `\setlength{\footparindent}{0em}` doesn't have any effect.
Why is my `\setlength` ignored?

Some longer example

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\newcommand\authordetail[1]{
        \setlength{\footparindent}{0em}
        \protect\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{#1}}%


\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{article}

\title{The Big Book of Conundrums\thanks{reprinted with permission}}

\author{The Author\authordetail{The author was born long time ago, and the wrote this book}}
\date{March 1984}

\maketitle

\newpage

Some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

% \newcommand\authordetail[1]{
%         %\setlength{\footparindent}{0em}
%         \protect\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{#1}}%

\chapterstyle{article}

\title{The Big Book of Conundrums\thanks{reprinted with permission}}

\author{The Author\thanks{The author was born long time ago, and the wrote this book}}
\date{March 1984}

\renewcommand{\thanksfootmark}{%
                \thanksscript{\thefootnote}
                    }

\begin{document}



\maketitle

\newpage

Some text\footnote{Some text description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but I haven't asked my question properly. Your solution is not what I am looking for. I'll edit my question